# Setting Varchar in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar

I have set varchar to 8000 but still not able to store more than 255 character in sql server.

Comment: You need to provide more information

Comment: I have read question and can only assume bug in sql server.

Comment: @TDP this is unlikely to be a bug, and more likely to be user misunderstanding. We have far too little information, however, to give any type of valid answer to this question. To the OP, please update your post; have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to post a qusetion properly. Thanks.

Comment: @Larnu - It was an attempt at humour...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue looks that the insertion should be a success but while retrieving through the QA, you see only 255 characters back.  This is just a **visual problem** and nothing more. Just change this limitation under the **Tools > Options > Results** in the SSMS where you have an option to change the **Maximum characters per column** option. Try changing to the desired value. Hope this helps!